# How to create a link on website by long-pressing in Internet browser?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, app-icons, usability, browser

I want to create a desktop icon to a link on a website by long pressing it. 
However, long-pressing the link does not have the function "Add to Home Screen" (in Chrome) and Page > Add to Home Screen (in Firefox). 
It adds the current page to the home screen, not the link pressed long.

I need this function because some website urls does not reflect the current page, but instead the early clickable link to the website does it. So having the possibility to add the url ask an icon to home screen would help me to maintain track of the articles that I want to read again regularly (so bookmarks not sufficient).

Internet browsers: Chrome, Firefox
OS: Oreo 8.0
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is, that when you press a link, it directs you to the desired page, but the URL automatically changes to a more general one, and therefore you cannot create a home screen shortcut.

I found a very simple solution to this problem. Hope it works for you as it worked for me. I did it in chrome. It should also work for Firefox.

Put your phone into airplane mode, then long press on the link, and select 'copy link address' then paste the link in the URL bar, and press enter. As soon as it directs you to the 'connection failed' page, go to the three dots menu and select 'add to home screen, rename the shortcut, and press ok.

The shortcut will now appear on your home screen. And when pressed, will direct you to the desired page.

If it still gives you the wrong page, then try all of the above, using incognito mode.

Comment: I think this is a stable and good workaround: flying mode state and insertion there. Incognito will not help here.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 i tested my answer, using Gmail.com because that was one site i could think of that whenever i type it in, it redirects me to a very long url. And even in airplane mode, it redirected me to a long link, because it recognized the link. This did not happen in incognito, and i was able to stay on Gmail.com with no problems. Hence my suggestion on incognito.

Comment: Thank for the explanation! I will test it next time if the aeroplane mode fails.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 no problem. just to clarify, you would need both, airplane mode and incognito.